# Can a foreign key be used for two primary keys?

Tags: database-design, erd, address

I'm still a beginner in sql and I have to transform this relation between clients and addresses and vendors and adresses. This uses 2 primary keys(1 for the vendors and 1 for the clients). My question is, is it better practice to use two foreign keys(one per ID)(second picture) or one foreign key that is being referred by the two primary keys(last picture)?

Thank you very much

[image: ERD]

[image: Proposition 1]

[image: Proposition 2]

Comment: Vendors and Clients are both subclasses of a superclass that might be called contacts.  A contact has an address.

Comment: So, it is okay to have the same foreign key for the both of them?

Answer (score 1):

You got it backwards: address is an attribute of a client or vendor, so the latter two should reference the (missing) ID of an address.

Comment: Shouldn't the foreign key be in the n side of the relation? Unless you talk about the orientation of the arrows that I just noticed are opposed(The first two attributes are the ID of address btw)

Comment: What is "the n side of the relation"? And it's relationSHIP. Foreign key is where it is _foreign_, that is, defined elsewhere.

Comment: A foreign key need not be unique in the column(s) where it is stored.  A primary key must be unique in the column(s) where it is stored. A foreign key references a logical key, generally a primary key.

Comment: Both the client table and the vendor table have a 1:N relationship with the address table, according to the diagram.  If there was only one table instead of two, say client, then in order for one client to have multiple addresses, you would have the address table reference the client table, i.e. you would place the foreign key on the "N" side (rather than the "1" side) of the 1:N relationship.  So the OP is asking how to have the address table serve two masters in that manner. Changing the direction of referencing doesn't seem to be a solution to me under those conditions.